# Split a string into exactly two strings in php

Tags: php

I need to split a string into exactly two parts.

Example:

```
$str = 'abc def ghi jkl'
```

Result:

```
$arr[0] = 'abc'
$arr[1] = 'def ghi jkl'
```

I tried

```
explode(' ', $str);
```

but it is giving me all the parts of the string. 
How do you combine the rest of the array would be a better question i guess?

Thanks for your help~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
explode(' ', $str, 2)
```

Read more about it at http://php.net/explode.

Comment: you beat me to it, by 10 secs! ^^

Comment: And I had trouble getting enough characters into this answer for it to be accepted... ;)

Comment: @deceze exactly same ... +1 for faster

Comment: @PraveenKumar looks likes so also give the previllage for the user have ik rep to write without the captcah code

Comment: @NullPointer Lets file a bug to SO! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `limit = 2` parameter.

#### Example:

```
<?php
$str = 'one|two|three|four';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

// negative limit (since PHP 5.1)
print_r(explode('|', $str, -1));
?>
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two|three|four
)
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

In your question, you can use this way:

```
explode(' ', $str, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try  the explode

```
explode(' ',$str , 2)
```

or try

```
$new= preg_split('/(\s)/', $str, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```